# 404 on _next assets after deploying to Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js, github-actions, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my next app to gh pages but only the index and 404 pages are displaying. All other pages, images, js and css files are returning a 404 error - everything inside the `_next` folder.

After some research, I found a popular solution to this issue was adding a `.nojekyll` file into the output folder to prevent jekyll from ignoring files prefixed with `_` which I've tried but the files remain missing.

Here is my gh action to building and deploy the app -

```
name: Deploy Next.js site to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow one concurrent deployment
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  # Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
          run:
            working-directory: ./docs
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Detect package manager
        id: detect-package-manager
        run: |
          if [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/docs/yarn.lock" ]; then
            echo "::set-output name=manager::yarn"
            echo "::set-output name=command::install"
            echo "::set-output name=runner::yarn"
            exit 0
          elif [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/docs/package.json" ]; then
            echo "::set-output name=manager::npm"
            echo "::set-output name=command::ci"
            echo "::set-output name=runner::npx --no-install"
            exit 0
          else
            echo "Unable to determine packager manager"
            exit 1
          fi
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "16"
          cache: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }}
      - name: Restore cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            .next/cache
          # Generate a new cache whenever packages or source files change.
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-${{ hashFiles('**.[jt]s', '**.[jt]sx') }}
          # If source files changed but packages didn't, rebuild from a prior cache.
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }} ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.command }}
      - name: Build with Next.js
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next build
      - name: Static HTML export with Next.js
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next export
      - name: nojekyll
        run: touch ./out/.nojekyll
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
        with:
          path: ./docs/out


  # Deployment job
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
```

I've checked the artifact that gets deployed and all intended files are there.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

1. In the `public` folder add file `.nojekyll`
2. In `package.json` add

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist -t true"
```

3. then run this command

```bash
yarn generate
yarn deploy
```

The file `.nojekyll` will be copied to the `dist` folder.

I'm using Nuxt app but the idea is the same.